# Docker does not start cpp application

Tags: c++, docker, dockerfile

i am trying to run a `cpp` application within docker.After i have built the `executable` and created the `Dockerfile` , i can not run it inside docker for some reason:

**main.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>
#include<thread>
#include<string>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    std::cout<<"Started daemon..."<<std::endl;
    std::string hostString(argv[1]);
    std::cout<<"HostName:"<<hostString<<std::endl; 
    std::cout<<"Port:"<<std::stoi(argv[2])<<std::endl;
    int i=0;
    while(true){
      std::cout<<"Iterations:"<<i++<<std::endl;
      std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(1));
      if(i++>10000) i=0;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM  ubuntu:latest
RUN mkdir -p /home/dockerc
COPY . /home/dockerc
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/dockerc/main","127.0.0.1","8350"]
```

**dockerc folder**

- **main.cpp**
- **main.exe**
- **Dockerfile**

I run the following:
`g++ main main.cpp`
 `docker build app .` 
 `docker images`  (it shows that `app`  image is created)
 `docker run app`

The build is succesfull but when i hit the `run` it looks like it blocks.It just does not continue.

[image]

What is wrong?Could someone help me ?I am new to docker.

**P.S** After waiting out for like 10 minutes i get long error message that begins  with the following:

```
$ docker run cpapp
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: container a575e463f193dbc475aab78c1810486e23981a50c                                                           0b731f9c891c4143d0ed5b3 encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The compute system exited unexpecte                                                                                                                                       dly. (0xc0370106)
```

Comment: `std::cout<<"HostName:"<<argv[1]<<std::endl; std::cout<<"Port:"<<std::stoi(argv[2])<<std::endl;` You try to access commandline parameters while I can't see that your program is started with any. That will probably give you a segmentation fault, and the program immediately stops.

Answer (score 2):

You should put the complete path in the `ENTRYPOINT` and add the parameters to your program.

This Dockerfile does the job:

```
FROM  ubuntu:latest
RUN mkdir -p /home/dockerc
COPY . /home/dockerc
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/dockerc/main", "hostname", "8000"]
```

replacing `hostname` and `8000` with the hostname and port that you need.

**Edit**

I tested your program in Linux, and to make it run I had to:

1) compile for c++11 (because of `chrono`)

2) add `-t` to build the docker app

This is the complete list of commands to run:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -std=c++11
docker build -t app .
docker run app
```

and this is the output:

[image: bash output]

Comment: I have used this dockerfile but when i run `docker run [appname] .` it just does nothing .

Comment: See my updated answer. Note that the port in the Dockerfile must be an integer.
If it still does not work, it would be better to add an image of your bash or a description of the error that you see.

Comment: I updated my dockerfile and added an image as to what happens when i use `docker run `

Answer (score 1):

replace your `RUN cd...` by a `WORKDIR ...`

your cd does not what you expect in this context, and is forgotten at the next line

you can  also remove the `RUN cd...` line and put the whole path in the

ENTRYPOINT

line

Comment: I don't believe that's the primary problem.

Comment: I do not know if the C++ program is correct, but I am sure the `RUN cd...` line is useless

Comment: But what command you use to run a shell script?If my application is named `main.exe` and i am **already** in the working directory how should `ENTRYPOINT` be used?  `ENTRYPOINT ["./main"]` ?

Comment: the simplest is what Amedeo said, you can also use WORKDIR, or `RUN cd the_correct_directory ampersandampersand ./main`  sorry on my phone I do not find the symbol for ampersand

Comment: yes if you are already in  the correct directory, you are correct

Comment: I have tried both with `WORKDIR` and `ENTRYPOINT` and it just does nothing ...it just waits forever.

Comment: you can also `docker run -it ubuntu:latest bash` and then you type the commands of the Dockerfile (not the directives like RUN) and see what works , well you will need `docker cp` which is not user friendly

Comment: So i got an error after waiting it out `Error response from daemon ; container [id] encountered an error during CreateProcess:failure in a Windows system call: The compute system exited unexpectedly`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180430/discussion-between-bercovici-adrian-and-user2915097).